# Proposition $3.1$ of Chapter $4$ of Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

> $3.1$ Proposition. Let $\sigma \subset T_pM$ be a two-dimensional space of the tangent space $T_pM$ and let $x, y \in \sigma$ be two linearly independet vectors. Then
> $$K(x,y) = \frac{(x,y,x,y)}{|x \wedge y|^2}$$
> does not depend on the choice of the vectors $x, y, \in \sigma$.

> Proof. To avoid calculating, we observe that we can pass from the basis $\{ x, y \}$ of $\sigma$ to any other basis $\{ x', y' \}$ by iterating the following elementary transformations:

> (a) $\{ x, y \} \rightarrow \{ y, x \}$,

> (b) $\{ x, y \} \rightarrow \{ \lambda x, y \}$,

> (c) $\{ x, y \} \rightarrow \{ x + \lambda y, y \}$.

> It is easy to see that $K(x,y)$ is invariant by such transformations and that completes the proof. $\square$

I would like to know if my thought about why $K(x,y)$ is invariant by such transformations is correct.

Once that $|x \wedge y|^2 = (\det A)^2 |x' \wedge y'|^2$, where $A$ is a linear transformation that changes the basis $\{ x, y \}$ to the basis $\{ x', y' \}$ and a linear transformation is a composition of elementary transformations, it is sufficient show that $(x,y,x,y) = (\det E)^2 (Ex, Ey, Ex, Ey)$, where $E$ is one of the elementary transformations of the proof. Is it correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know if your thoughts are in the spirit of Do Carmo's book. Here is how I see it:

Now that we know that $K$ is unvariant under these three types of tranformations, pick two basis $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ of $\sigma\subset T_pM$. By the Gauss's elimination algorithm, we know that there is a finite sequence $(T_i)_{i\in \{1,\ldots,k\}}$ of transformations of the above form such that applying this sequence to $(x_1,y_1)$ gives $(x_2,y_2)$, *i.e* $x_2 = T_kT_{k-1}\cdots T_1 x_1$ and similarly for $y_2$ and $y_1$. Hence, $K(x_1,y_1)=K(T_k \circ \cdots \circ T_1 x_1,T_k \circ \cdots \circ T_1 y_1) = K(x_2,y_2)$, and we have shown that $K$ is a function of $\sigma$, that is is independent from the chosen basis.